# Does IndexedDB need to be closed other than on upgrade?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage, indexeddb

In my one-page Backbone application, I open indexedDB and never close it, assuming the browser will close it automatically if the user navigates away from the app.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Should indexedDB be periodically closed, or closed when the window.unload event is fired, or is upgrading it the only time I ever need to close it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the documentation from [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-IndexedDB-20130704/#database-concept):

> When a connection is initially created it is in opened state. The
>   connection can be closed through several means. If the connection is
>   GCed or execution context where the connection is created is destroyed
>   (for example due to the user navigating away from that page), the
>   connection is closed. The connection can also be closed explicitly
>   using the steps for closing a database connection. When the connection
>   is closed the closePending flag is always set to true if it hasn't
>   already been.

There is no need to close explicitly the connection, the browser should handle that.